# Grails Mail plugin - what is the proper way of using default content when sending empty mails?

Tags: grails

I added to Config.groovy default mail body by adding this line:

```
 grails.mail.default.body = "Test body"
```

and then I am passing adress, subject and body from form by params in a sendMail method:

```
sendMail {
    to params.adress
    subject params.title
    body params.body
}
```

It works fine if params.body is not empty, but when user ignores this field the default body is not added to mail - the mail cant be sent without body.

```
Class
grails.plugin.mail.GrailsMailException
Message
message has no content, use text(), html() or body() methods to set content
```

What mistake I did here? Is there some special way I need to handle default content of mail body, subject or other fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mail plugin has [special support](https://github.com/gpc/grails-mail/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/mail/MailMessageBuilder.groovy#L68) for `default.to` and `default.from` but not `default.body` (or subject, or anything else).  You could handle it yourself:

```
sendMail {
    to params.adress
    subject params.title
    body(params.body ?: grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.default.body)
}
```

but the plugin won't do it for you.

Comment: This answers why I couldn't use grails.mail.default.body like in my example. Simple and good answer, thank you!